# How to access users E-Mail after your app requests it

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have already gotten permission from twitter to request e-mails and enabled it in my app.

I'm using Abraham's OAuth.

My problem is that I don't know the parameter for accessing a users e-mail, and I can't find it in twitter's documentation.

Here's the code where I would grab it:

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($CONSUMER_KEY, $CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
        $params =array();
        $params['include_entities']='false';
        $content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials',$params);

        if($content && isset($content->screen_name) && isset($content->name))
        {
            $_SESSION['name']=$content->name;
            $_SESSION['image']=$content->profile_image_url;
            $_SESSION['twitter_id']=$content->screen_name;


            //redirect to main page.
```

I would assume now that in $content is some parameter for the users e-mail address that they consented for me to take. I've tried "email", "email_address", "e-mail", and "e-mail_address" but those were all undefined.

I would like to know what the parameter is to access a user's e-mail.

Comment: Have you echoed or printed the $content array to see if it is in there?

Comment: Simply breaks my code to echo it for some reason, I did try that first. It doesn't even show up in my source if I echo a script to try to alert it or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is what that $params array is for. Who knew?

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($CONSUMER_KEY, $CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
        $params =array();
        $params['include_entities']='false';
        $params['include_email']='true';//Added this line
        $content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials', $params);

        if($content && isset($content->screen_name) && isset($content->name))
        {
            $_SESSION['name']=$content->name;
            $_SESSION['image']=$content->profile_image_url;
            $_SESSION['twitter_id']=$content->id;
            $_SESSION['email']=$content->email;//The parameter is 'email'
            //redirect to main page.
```